# How to access field of a document in firestore collection in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access photoUrl of user on the basis of ID, but unfortunalty am not getting hat is deserved.

I have attached a picture of my firestore collection, Please tell me how I can access photoUrl.
[image: User is the main collection, document on the basis of ID are document and each document have some fielld I want to access photourl on the basis of ID.]
User is the main collection, document on the basis of ID are document and each document have some fielld I want to access photourl on the basis of ID.

`getImage(id) { this.users=this.db.collection('user').doc(id).collection('photurl').valueChanges(); console.log(this.users); }`

I have implemented the code in the answered but facing a new issue, the function continuously calls itself as the resulting picture is not displaying.

`<div *ngFor="let Question of Questions "> <img src="{{ getImage(Question.authorNo) }}"  class="d-block ui-w-40 rounded-circle" alt="">`

This is my html, I have used iterator because I have many question, I am getting authorID of author and match it with the userID, if any userID matches AuthorID get it photoUrl and display it
My function getting photoUrl is as follow

`getImage(id) { this.db.doc(`user/${id}`).valueChanges().subscribe(user => {
this.user = user;
this.url = this.user.photoUrl;
//console.log(this.url);

});
return this.url;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a an Observable to subscribe to the user data and assign the photoUrl to a variable [Option 1] or you can then assign all of the user data to a user variable and use `user.photoUrl` in the template [Option 2].

**Option 1**

```
user: any;
photoUrl: string; 

...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.db.doc(`user/${id}`).valueChanges().subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
        this.photoUrl = user.photoUrl;
    });
}
```

**Option 2**

```
user: any; 

...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.db.doc(`user/${id}`).valueChanges().subscribe(user => this.user = user);
}
```

Edit: The data model you have currently doesn't lend an easy option to retrieve the photo url. It is recommended to save the photo url directly onto the question document like you are doing with the author id to prevent so many extra reads. Option 3 would allow you to do what you want but it isn't recommended.

**Option 3 NOT RECOMMENDED**

```
photoData = [];

...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.db.collection<any>('user').snapshotChanges().subscribe(snapshots => {
      snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        const url = snapshot.payload.doc.data().photoUrl;
        const id = snapshot.payload.doc.id;
        const data = { url, id };
        this.photoData.push(data);
      })
    });
}


getImage(id: string) {
  this.photoData.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      return item.url;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the first option, but I'm facing new issues, I have created a method and when the application start it repeats that function in an unending styles, It continously repeat itself, I have not place your suggestion in OnInit.

Comment: The issue is with your code then. Can you share some of it to see what’s going on?

Comment: @Abdullah I edited the original answer and it will work for what you need it to do but no matter which way you do it with your current data model it will result in too many reads and might cost a lot of money at the end of the day depending on how many questions and users you have.

Comment: The reason why I used 3rd option is, if user update his profile picture, then question will have the old picture and user profile will not be the same. Although proformance has impact on it

Comment: That makes sense. As an alternative, you could create a question component and add input properties for the question data and the user id for the *ngFor loop. Then each question component can subscribe to the individual user. I would get the user from a service and pipe shareReplay(1) to reduce calls to Firestore.